# the process that run from c++ misses an option occasionally

Tags: c++, linux

below is my code, the option "--graph" is missed some time, even in the same computer.

```
boost::filesystem::path cmd =
            boost::filesystem::path(my::Cmdline::get_workspace())
            / "bin" / "cmdbin";

char const *argv[1024] = {};
int idx = 0;
argv[idx++] = cmd.c_str();
argv[idx++] = ("--graph=" + conf.root()).c_str();
argv[idx++] = "--file=/home/cmd/cmd.pid";
argv[idx++] = "--logfile=/home/cmd/cmd.log";


_exit(execvp(argv[0], (char **)argv));
```

```
// ps aux and grep the process

root     25323  4.3  0.0 1370872 10720 ?       S<l  17:11   0:00 /home/cmd/cmdbin --logfile=/home/cmd/cmd.log --file=/home/cmd/cmd.pid


// which should be

root     25323  4.3  0.0 1370872 10720 ?       S<l  17:11   0:00 /home/cmd/cmdbin --graph=/home/cmd --file=/home/cmd/cmd.pid --logfile=/home/cmd/cmd.log
```

by the way, "conf.root()" is an inline function; is it related to the execvp? the argv is missing when give to it?

Comment: `("--graph=" + conf.root()).c_str();` immediately becomes a dangling pointer when the temporary string is destroyed. You should save `"--graph=" + conf.root()` to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `c_str` method of a temporary string object `("--graph=" + conf.root())`, which returns a pointer to that string object's internal buffer, which is no longer valid after the line.

You could use this instead:

```
std::string graph_option = "--graph=" + conf.root();
argv[idx++] = graph_option.c_str();
```

This string will not be deleted before `execvp`, because the variable will not go out of scope before.

The reason it worked sometimes with the invalid object is that the pointer returned will still point to where the buffer used to be. When you called `c_str` the object was still valid, and even if it wasn't you would still get something from the method, normally there is no check against using objects after they have been destructed.

If that buffer happens not to be overwritten between the destructor call and the use of the value, the old value will be read and everything seems to work. Depending on the string implementation and the size of the string the buffer may be on the heap or inside the string object itself (on the stack). Either way the memory could be reused or not. You yould use a debugger to examine what actually happens on your system, but any change even to unrelated parts of your program, to the standard library or to the compiler may change the result.

A key concept in C++ is the term of "undefined behaviour". It means that there is absolutely no restriction on what happens in your program if certain conditions are violated. This allows the implementers of the language (mainly compilers and the standard library) to make optimizations assuming that undefined behaviour never happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I'm still confused with why it works sometime? Could c_str get the string from invalid object?

Comment: @rabia_2705 [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (that your code causes) can have any effect, including crasing, giving you a garbage string, and working as intended, depending on the moon phase.